# Can Borel subgroups be partitioned into sets of roots?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, root-systems

I'm doing a project in algebraic geometry where Borel subgroups play a very important role, but my supervisor made a comment that confused me.

Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group and let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus. Consider a borel subgroup $B$ containing $T$ and let $\phi$ be the set of roots of $G$ with respect to $T$. My supervisor said that $B$ can be partitioned into $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$ but I haven't been able to find this in any book or article so my question is: How accurate is this statement? And if it isn't accurate, what would be a more correct interpretation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the "Positive roots and simple roots" section [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) for a start.

Comment: The pair $(T, G)$ determines a root system, and a choice of Borel $B$ corresponds to a choice of positive roots in that system. So a choice of $B$ is the partition, but $B$ itself only contains root subgroups corresponding to positive roots (or only negative roots, depending on the convention of the book you’re following).

Comment: Thank you @Joppy, this makes much more sense. Since all Borel $B$ are conjugate to each other, does the choice of $B$ actually change the root system in a meaningful way?

Comment: Yep that’s right. Having a positive root system is very handy for studying root systems, but all choices of positive systems are conjugate in the Weyl group and so “look alike”.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Joppy: Maybe make that a short answer.